# Modificador de acceso "Internal" ¿Para que sirve? C#

Tags: c#

¿Que utilidad tiene ese modificador? No me queda del todo claro, cuando dejas que Visual Studio cree métodos por ti (por ejemplo, escribiendo un método que no existe en un objeto y que IntelliSense implemente por ti el método...) Siempre (o casi siempre) se implemente el metodo con el modificador de acceso `Internal`, en vez de public, private o protected...

¿Porque lo hace? ¿Que sentido tienen los Internal?

Comment: La pregunta no es mala, pero esta tan mal planteada que las 4 respuestas que te dieron son la copia del manual, que es lo que vos decis que no entendes. Tu pregunta concreta seria (IMHO): porque al crear un metodo automaticamente, VS le pone el modificador internal por defecto?

Comment: Public: Todo mundo puede utilizar el elemento. Private, solo la clase que lo declara lo puede usar, Protected: La clase que lo define y las subclases que hereden de esa clase pueden usarlo, Internal: La clase que lo define y las otras clases en el mismo ensamblado ( en el mismo proyecto) pueden acceder a el, Protected Internal: Las clases que heredan sea el ensamblado que sea, y las otras clases en el mismo ensamblado pueden acceder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resumen:

**internal** es para el alcance del ensamblado (es decir, solo accesible desde el código en el mismo .exe o .dll). Los miembros internos solo son accesibles dentro del ensamblado por herencia (su tipo derivado) o por instancia de clase.

[image: imgan]

**Referencia:**

[dotnetbull: qué es el modificador de acceso en C#](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/10/public-protected-private-internal-access-modifier-in-c.html) (Info en Inglés)

**Ampliado:**

Clases / métodos de utilidad o ayudantes a los que le gustaría acceder desde muchas otras clases dentro del mismo ensamblado, pero a los que desea asegurarse de que el código en otros ensamblajes no pueda acceder.

Desde la [referencia oficial C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal):

> Un uso común del acceso interno está en el desarrollo basado en componentes porque permite que un grupo de componentes coopere de forma privada sin estar expuesto al resto del código de la aplicación. Por ejemplo, un marco para construir interfaces gráficas de usuario podría proporcionar clases de Control y Formularios que cooperen utilizando miembros con acceso interno. Como estos miembros son internos, no están expuestos al código que usa el marco.

También puede usar el modificador interno junto con el atributo [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) de nivel de ensamblaje para crear ensamblajes "amigos" a los que se les concede acceso especial a las clases internas del ensamblaje de destino.

Esto puede ser útil para la creación de conjuntos de pruebas unitarias que luego pueden llamar a los miembros internos del conjunto que se probarán. Por supuesto, a ningún otro ensamblado se le concede este nivel de acceso, por lo que cuando libera su sistema, se mantiene la encapsulación.

Answer (score 1):

El modificador internal hace que los metodos y propiedades definidas de este modo sean accesibles para elementos que se compilen en el mismo binario, sin importar el entorno.
Es decir, si vos queres hacer un framework o una biblioteca y que sus elementos se accedan entre si con mas facilidad los declaras con internal, de manera que dentro de tu framework puedan accederse, pero cuando alguien mas quiera usarlos con tu assembly compilado como referencia no pueda accederlos y solo vea los metodos que voy hayas expuesto.

Answer (score 1):

Tomado de [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

> Solo se puede tener acceso a los tipos internos o los miembros desde los archivos del mismo ensamblado.
>
> Un uso común del acceso interno se da en el desarrollo basado en componentes porque permite que un grupo de componentes cooperen de manera privada sin estar expuesto al resto del código de la aplicación. Por ejemplo, un marco para crear interfaces gráficas de usuario podría proporcionar las clases Control y Form que cooperan mediante miembros con acceso interno. Como estos miembros son internos, no se exponen al código que usa el marco de trabajo.

Básicamente un método internal es publico pero solo dentro del assembly que lo contiene.

No quiero ser redundante con la documentación. Conceptualmente, lo que haces con los métodos internals es hacer un método público dentro de la librería pero con la diferencia que **no quieres exponerlo como parte de la API** de la librería.

Una buena práctica (y por eso lo hace Visual Studio) es hacer los métodos se hagan primero `internal` y después, una vez que decides cual va a ser la API de tu aplicación, comenzar a exponer los mismos como `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Esta relacionado con la `programacion orientada a objetos`, quizas la doc oficial aporte algo de claridad con ejemplos

[internal (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal)

basicmente defines como sera la accesibilidad de la clase, por ejemplo si defienes en una librerias una `class` como internal solo podras utilizar dentro de esa libreria y no desde otra que haga referencia

[Niveles de accesibilidad (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)

en el link menciona

> internal:  El acceso está limitado al ensamblado actual.